# Skipped 320 frames doing too much on its main thread

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

**Edit**

The Main issue was in the fragment I opened with the eventbus. I introduced delay over there which caused the issue. Anyway thanks for the help.

**Main Post**

Yet another skipped frames question. So here is my code

```
public class ProductDisplayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductDisplayAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Item> productList;
    private Table<String,Integer,Item> cartTable = HashBasedTable.create();
    private OnItemChanged itemChangedListener;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private Picasso picasso;
    public ProductDisplayAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> items)
    {
        this.context = mContext;
        this.productList = items;
        this.picasso = Picasso.with(context);
        this.picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    }

    private Item getItem(int position) {
        return new Item(productList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_product,parent,false);
        this.viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        viewHolder.cartAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewHolder.numberButton.setNumber("1");
                viewHolder.viewSwitcher.showNext();
                if(itemChangedListener != null)
                {
                    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    Item product = productList.get(position);
                    product.setTotalQuantity(1);
                    notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    productList.set(position, product);
                    cartTable.put(product.getId(), product.getMetricPosition(), product);
                    itemChangedListener.onItemAdded(cartTable, 1);
                }
            }
        });
        viewHolder.numberButton.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue) {
                if(itemChangedListener != null)
                {
                    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    Item product = productList.get(position);
                    product.setTotalQuantity(newValue);
                    notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    productList.set(position, product);
                    cartTable.put(product.getId(), product.getMetricPosition(), product);
                    itemChangedListener.onItemAdded(cartTable, newValue-oldValue);

                }
            }
        });
        viewHolder.clickView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(productList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        });
        return this.viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder mViewHolder, int position) {
        Item product = getItem(position);
        picasso.load(product.getImageUrl()).fit().into(viewHolder.productImage);
        String price = CurrencyUtils.getCurrencySymbol(product.getCurrency()) + product.getPrice().get(product.getMetricPosition());
        viewHolder.productPrice.setText(price);
        viewHolder.productName.setText(product.getName());
        viewHolder.productQuantity.setText(product.getQuantity().get(product.getMetricPosition()));
        viewHolder.productQuantity.setTypeface(FontUtils.getRegularTypeFace());
        viewHolder.productQuantity.setOnClickListener(dialogClickListener);
        if(product.getTotalQuantity() > 0)
        {
            viewHolder.viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);
            viewHolder.numberButton.setNumber(String.valueOf(product.getTotalQuantity()),false);
        }
        else if(product.getStock() > 0)
        {
            viewHolder.viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
            viewHolder.cartAdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            viewHolder.cartAdd.setTag(false);
            viewHolder.cartAdd.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cart_add));
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
            viewHolder.cartAdd.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cart_soldout));
        }

        removeButtonShadow(viewHolder.productQuantity);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView productImage,cartAdd;
        TextView productName;
        TextView productPrice;
        Button productQuantity;
        ElegantNumberButton numberButton;
        ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
        View clickView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.clickView = itemView;
            productImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            productPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            productQuantity = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
            cartAdd = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_add);
            numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_button);
            viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_switcher);
        }

    }

    private View.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment previousDialog = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(StringConstants.DIALOG_TAG);
            if(previousDialog != null)
            {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(previousDialog);
            }
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            QuantityDialogFragment mFragment = QuantityDialogFragment.newInstance(getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()),getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMetricPosition());
            mFragment.setQuantityListener(new OnQuantityChosen() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectQuantity(int position) {
                    Item item = getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    item.setMetricPosition(position);
                    item.setTotalQuantity(0);
                    productList.set(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),item);
                    notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
            mFragment.show(fragmentTransaction,StringConstants.DIALOG_TAG);
        }
    };

    private void removeButtonShadow(Button button)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
            button.setStateListAnimator(null);
    }

    public void setOnItemChangedListener(OnItemChanged onItemChangedListener)
    {
        this.itemChangedListener = onItemChangedListener;
    }


}
```

I am experiencing frame skips especially when I encounter the following lines,

```
viewHolder.clickView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(product);
            }
        });
```

I could not figure out where the problem arises from. But once I click the recyclerview Item, I am having a visible and significant frameskip with the compiler throwing 300+ frame skips in the trace. Could anyone narrow it down and suggest some change ?

**Edit**

Here is my Eventbus Subscriber.

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.BACKGROUND)
    public void onProductClicked(Item product)
    {
        Fragment fragment = ProductLandingFragment.newInstance(product);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(StringConstants.FRAGMENT_CATEGORIES_TAG));
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,fragment,StringConstants.FRAGMENT_PRODUCT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: ah, the horror of way too large methods!

Comment: What are the subscribers for Eventbus are doing? I think the trouble must be there.

Comment: The subscribers changes the fragment.  The RecycleView is inside a ViewPager which is held in a fragment(UI Fragment). The subscriber just replaces the UI Fragment

Comment: this code is so horrible that you might get hired at my company

Comment: Code Optimization aint done yet. This my code I am working on. If all the features work correctly then I would start optimizing it.

Answer (score 3):

Do not assign listeners in onBind at all. I think you misunderstand the point of recycleview. This is how you should do it:

- onCreateViewHolder should initialize the view, find the views and add listeners
- onBind should update ViewHolder data so those listeners have the proper data when fired

You wanna make sure there's as little code as possible in onBind because it gets called a lot, especially during scrolling.

For example do not do any kind of code initialization there (i.e Picasso), do it once in the adapter constructor.

Use multiple view types so you dont need to deal with dynamic changes either.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious mistake you are making is instantiating to many OnClickListeners (or objects, in general) in `onBindViewHolder()` callback.

You can easily fix this issue by instantiating only one listener per button type, for example:

Place it outside `onBindViewHolder()` (e.g. Adapter's constructor):

```
View.OnClickListener productListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Product product = adapter.items.get((int) view.getTag)); // get item for position
        EventBus.getDefault().post(product);
    }
}
```

Then, in `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
...
viewHolder.clickView.setOnClickListener(productListener);
viewHolder.setTag(position);
```

By reusing `OnClickListeners` you are saving a lot of CPU time and memory. Instantiating isn't that expensive but you are freeing lots of memory and make `Garbage Collector` work constantly on freeing resources that are no longer used.

What @abbath said in comments may be an issue too.